# Ler meta com javascript

Tags: javascript

Muitas apis da google usam javascript para funcionar, na autenticação eles usam `<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="api-key">` e o javascript le isto para autenticar, como eles fazem para o JavaScript ler isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar `document.querySelector` para selecionar elementos do DOM/página e extraír o que procuras.

Para ler o exemplo que indicaste podes fazer assim:

```
var apiKey = document.querySelector('[name="google-signin-client_id"]').getAttribute('content');
console.log(apiKey);
```

O que esse código faz, por passos:

- `document.querySelector` - procurar na página por um elemento que acerte com o seletor passado, onde o atributo `name` fôr: _"google-signin-client_id"_
- `getAttribute` - ir buscar a esse elemento o valor do atributo passado ao método

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @TheCoder fico contente de ajudar :)